# Reaction involving Hydroperoxide group

Tags: organic-chemistry

**THE GIVEN QUESTION**
[image]

**MY ATTEMPT**
[image]
[image]
The answer to this question was not given in my book.I want to know if this is the correct reaction mechanism and these are the products which are formed.

Comment: Within minutes of asking the question, it has a down vote. Can anyone care to explain what is wrong with it so I can improve it?

Comment: definitely. your answer is right. this link may help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumene_process

Comment: regarding to your query you raised in the form of a comment, I think it may be a standard reaction for graduates or post graduates. for undergraduate level, not so.

Comment: @user93057 Thank you. I had identified the question was related to the Cumene Process mechanism but was confused about the shifting of groups and therefore asked the question. Thanks for verifying that it is correct

Comment: You're welcome. it is based on just two main factors: the oxygen linked with hydrogen is more electrophilic as it has lesser steric hindrance than that beside it and that the phenyl group with OCH3 is more active towards EAS, which you've identified well.

Comment: Welcome to chem.SE. Have a look at the [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour)  to have an idea what kind of questions are accepted on this site. Yes, downvotes can be discouraging and I assure you most of the users here(me including) has faced downvotes. It can't be helped. Downvoters remain anonymous unless specified. All you can do is improve your post, ask good, well researched question, format your question to look good, use software to draw chemical structure rather than clicking pictures. Hope, it helps